# Run Detox tests on ios physical device?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, e2e-testing, detox

I am currently working on a react native project using Detox for e2e tests.
I can run tests on my android device changing detox configuration

```
"android-device": {
      binaryPath: "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk",
      build: "cd android && ./gradlew app:assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release && cd ..",
      type: "android.attached",
      device: {
        avdName: "RF8M80C2LHR",
      },
    },
```

I want to do the same thing with my iPhone device but doesn't work the same way that works with android.
Any recommendation on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Not supported. There is a pretty long issue, explaining why.

https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/95

Comment: Leo Natan - Is this still the case for iOS devices? Can I run detox tests on real Android device instead? If yes, is there some guide? Thanks!

Comment: For iOS, yes. For Android, it is supported as far as I know, but I don’t think we’ve written a guide. Best way is to start a new question and we’ll try to answer.

Comment: It is possible to run on a real Android device https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.Android.md

Comment: @LéoNatan any update on running detox tests on iOS devices? will it be in v21? 

Comment: @benmneb This is the second time you've pinged me on Detox. I am no longer working at Wix and have no involvement with the development of Detox.